# DSLForge editor to support ANTLR v4

Tags: antlr4, dsl

I have gone through http://dslforge.org/getting-started-generate-ace-editor/ but this supports ANTLR v3.3 only. Can it be tweaked to work with v4? I tried replacing antlr-all.min.js with a antlr4 js but that did not work.

Comment: ANTLR v4 is not a non-breaking release. Actually ANTLR major upgrades are always breaking. Thus, if you do want something to work with new releases, hack it seriously.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to use DSL Forge with ANTLR v4, you need a working JavaScript target, which is not publicly available afaik. Until now the most stable JavaScript target for ANTLR is the one shipped with ANTLR v3.3.